# Markowitz Pivoting to reduce size of a dense integer system

Tags: linear-algebra, sparse-matrix, matrix

I am dealing with a large sparse integer matrix that I need to find the nullspace of. I've seen Markowitz Pivoting come up in several places discussing similar problems such as here:

http://www.mapleprimes.com/posts/41191-Solving-Sparse-Linear-Systems-In-Maple

And in the MAGMA documentation under the sparse null space algorithm. How can one use this technique (or similarly perhaps, the Structured Gaussian Elimination mentioned above it) to reduce a sparse matrix to a dense, small matrix? I understand that you can eliminate variables with regular Gaussian Elimination, but how does one retrieve those after solving the new system?

Comment: How large is this matrix? A sparse QR or sparse SVD algorithm will be more numerically stable than sparse LU. If your matrix is very large, iterative procedures also exist.

Comment: Sorry, the system is integer, so the algorithm should be exact. I edited it into the question.

Comment: I am currently working on a matrix with size 12000, but I'd like to be able to go bigger later.